# How to save a FileObject from SFTP as local file?

Tags: java, xml, sftp, vfs

I want to write a java program to test an interface, that communicates via xml-files over SFTP. The idea of the interface is that one side uploads an xml-file, then the other side processes it, deletes it and uploads another xml-file as acknowledgement.

What my program is supposed to do, is upload an xml-file, wait for it to vanish,  wait for the response, save it as local file and then check the correctness of the response. I implemented this using org.apache.commons.vfs2 and FileObjects and can successfully upload an xml-file, wait for it to vanish and check the existence of the acknowledgement-file. But as soon as i try to parse the file as document using the code

```
    FileObject ackFileObject = VFS.getManager().resolveFile("sftp://user@sftp.server.com/SFTPfolder/file.xml");
    File ackFile = new File(ackFileObject.getName().getPath());
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(ackFile);
```

I get a FileNotFoundException, because the documentBuilder tries to read the file from `"C:/SFTPfolder/"` instead of reading it from the project path. Also `"new File(ackFileObject.getName().getPath());"` doesn't create a new File.

Is there an easy solution to fix this? How can I save a `FileObject` I get from `VFS.getManager().resolveFile()` as local File, so I can parse it as document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `copyFrom()` method. You need to define your remote and your local paths first:

You have already defined your remote file:

```
    FileObject ackFileObject = VFS.getManager()
                   .resolveFile("sftp://user@sftp.server.com/SFTPfolder/file.xml");
```

Now define the path you want to copy your remote path to:

```
    FileObject ackFileObjectLocal = VFS.getManager()
                  .resolveFile(localFilePath);
```

Where you have to set up `localFilePath` variable before or set it as a constant.

Then use: `ackFileObjectLocal.copyFrom(ackFileObject, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);`

So now you have your file downloaded and can wrap it with File object to proceed with your processing.